# C# Regular Expressions info from urls

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following urls:

```
http://vk.com/video#/video219171498_166164529

http://vk.com/video?gid=21095903#/video-21095903_165699050

http://vk.com/video#/video219171498_166164529
```

I need to take the info 'video219171498_166164529' from these strings. Maybe there is a code that can take 'video' and 19 symbols after. SORRY FOR MY ENGLISH

Comment: What you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if the title of your question is important or not, however to extend on the other peoples valid answers, if you did need(?) to use Regular expressions you could achieve the same outcome as the others. C# uses System.Text.RegularExpressions so you could do something like this to extract the "video..." string.

```
string pattern = "(video[\w-]+)";
string url = "http://blahblah/video-12341237293";

Match match = Regex.Match(url, pattern);
// Here you can test Match to check there was a match in the first place
// This will help with multiple urls that are dynamic rather than static like the above example

string result = match.Groups[1].Value;
```

In the above, result will be equal to the matching string within url. Using Match to check there was a match in the first place will mean you can put this in a loop and traverse a List/Array etc etc without needing to know the url values, or change the pattern for specific cases.

Anyway, you might not need Regex but incase you did, I hope the above helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually get the value by using only `Split()`.

```
string _str = "http://vk.com/video#/video219171498_166164529";
var _arr = _str.Split("/");
string _value = _arr[_arr.length - 1];
```

Comment: yes i can take from first link, but i can't write code for all thi links

Answer (score 1):

To improve the answer of 491243, I would to it that way :

```
 string _str = "http://vk.com/video#/video219171498_166164529";
 string _arr = _str.Split("/").Last();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string _str = "http://vk.com/video#/video219171498_166164529";

var index = _str.LastIndexOf("/");
var value = _str.SubString(index + 1);
```

be sure to add error handling